# count elements in variable with class '.item' jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

how can i count elements with the class item which is contained in a variable

so far http://jsfiddle.net/jGj4B/

```
var post = '<div/><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>';
alert($(post).find('.item').length);​ // i have tried .size() in place of .length
```

Comment: BTW you shouldn't be having a closing div tag right at the start...

Comment: ignore that, it is relevant but not to what i need in this question, but thankyou :)

Comment: Your variable is a string is it not?  Not DOM objects.

Comment: Here's what it should be: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/jGj4B/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `filter` instead of `find`:

```
$(post).filter('.item').length
```

`find` looks for descendent element, and there are none.

If you want both top-level items and descendants, you could do this:

```
$(post).find('.item').andSelf().filter(".item").length
```

Though wrapping it in a span as suggested in another answer is probably much more understandable.

---

**EDIT 7/19/2013:**  `andSelf` has been deprecated as of v1.8 and `addBack` should be used in its place.

```
$(post).find('.item').addBack().filter(".item").length
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to create a DOM object without actually appending it to the DOM. Something like:

```
var post = '<div/><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>';

// Create a dummy element:
var temp = $("<span />");

// Populate the HTML of that element with the data from your post variable
$(temp).html(post);

// Search the element as you normally would (if it were attached to the DOM)
$(temp).find(".item").length; // equals 4
```